# How to Package Xamarin Android Asset folder with files larger than 3gb

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Good day all,
Please I have some videos in my asset folder which I want to package with the APK in my xamarin android project, but brings the error:

```
1>AAPT : error : unable to process assets while packaging 'obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources.bk'
1>AAPT : error : packaging of 'obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources.bk' failed
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

But when I hard the files less than 1gb, everything was working fine. Please how can I resolve this and package up to 9gb into my personal app which will not be on the play store.
Thanks
Tim

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover, for your reply. Wow, I've been reading, but can i get a small tutorial that doesn't have anything to do with the play store. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to Package Xamarin Android Asset folder with files larger than 3gb

Since your assets are packaged into an `APK`, you are **limited by the max-size allowed by Android Market which is 100 MB**. As the Official documents said.

> Google Play currently requires that your APK file be no more than 100MB.

If you don't want to publish your app to Android Market, without the restriction , Android is just like Linux. 2GB file-size limit for Linux and also limit by the maximum available file-handle.